# Showing distinct rows with conditioning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Imagine we have a Pandas Dataframe with such a structure:

```
Date                Value    PercentageDifference
2018-04-08 13:40:00 0.001   0.000000
2018-04-08 13:41:00 5.000   4999.000000
2018-04-08 13:42:00 16.670  2.334000
2018-04-08 13:43:00 18.670  0.119976
```

How can one show only distinct rows of dataframe with certain conditions, for example if the Value=0.001 show this row and the next one following it:

```
Date                Value   PercentageDifference
2018-04-08 13:40:00 0.001   0.000000
2018-04-08 13:41:00 5.000   4999.000000
```

Is there only a lambda solution or it can be done easier with Pandas functionality?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your condition. Why the second row is involved in the results? Is that what you want? or that is happening and you don't want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `|` and `shift`

```
df[(df.Value==0.001)|(df.Value==0.001).shift()]
Out[414]: 
                 Date  Value  PercentageDifference
0  2018-04-0813:40:00  0.001                   0.0
1   2018-04-083:41:00  5.000                4999.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumed your Dataframe is called df.

```
idx = df['Value'] == 0.001
```

contains the rows with value==0.001

```
idx_os = np.roll(idx, 1)
```

contains the next rows (and yes also the first row, if the last one was of value == 0.001 - think about it, if you want this or not.

Then you have your rows with

```
df[idx | idx_os]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) to get the location of row with `Value=0.001` and then query for this and the next row.

```
idx = np.where([df['Value']==0.001][0])[0][0]
df.iloc[idx:idx+2]
```

Output:

```
   Date       Value   Percentage  Difference
2018-04-08  13:40:00    0.001     0.0
2018-04-08  13:41:00    5.000     4999.0
```